# Improper use of an expectation?

Tags: expected-value, notation

A derivation in a paper (theoretical ecology--there are often mathematical errors there) I am reading essentially uses the following line: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}=E\left[X_{i}\right]$. This strikes me as improper, as the left side of the equation is a random variable, while the right side of the equation is not. Am I correct? Even if this were not a problem, it would not make sense, unless $\left\{ X_{i}\right\} _{i}$ were identically distributed, right?

Comment: Well, its not technically correct because it doesn't specify which $i$ is used there. But you are right, it's generally not correct. It would be correct if this were an ergodic series and $n$ would go to infinity.

Comment: Some people confusingly use the notation "$E[X_i]$" as an abbreviation for the left hand side of your equation. That is indeed an abuse of notation, but if in the context of that paper it is used consistently and not confounded with "$E$" meant as an expectation, then its use is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, they continue making use of it as an expectation for the rest of the paper.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If the $X_i$ all have the same expectation, then putting an $E$ on the LHS would make it true for any $i$ on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

Well, its not technically correct because it doesn't specify which $i$ is used there. But you are right, it's generally not correct. It would be correct if this were an ergodic series and $n$ would go to infinity. – yoki

Some people confusingly use the notation "$E[X_i]$" as an abbreviation for the left hand side of your equation. That is indeed an abuse of notation, but if in the context of that paper it is used consistently and not confounded with "$E$" meant as an expectation, then its use is correct. – whuber

If the $X_i$ all have the same expectation, then putting an $E$ on the LHS would make it true for any $i$ on the right. – Glen_b